# How to create and use web services in ColdFusion

Tags: web-services, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

I tried creating a web service in ColdFusion, for that I just created a component with a function inside it having `access="remote"`

```
<cfcomponent displayname="testPost" hint="testing.." output="yes">
    <cfsetting enablecfoutputonly="true" showdebugoutput="true">
    <cffunction access="remote" output="true" name="testPostReq" displayname="testPostReq" description="testing" returntype="any"> 
        <cfset p=9>
        <cfreturn p>    
    </cffunction>   
</cfcomponent>
```

Now I wanted to call this webservice and I am trying to hit this in my browser, `https://sampleapp.xyz.com/DirectoryToCfc/CfcName.cfc?wsdl` but in browser I am getting "Unsupported Operation. Check application log for more details." when I checked application logs I saw this log there:

> "Warning","ajp-bio-8013-exec-4","09/27/21","12:57:55","COMPONENTUTILS","To use Component Browser, enable RDS Service using Administrator. Note: RDS is intended for development use only."

How can I deal with this, any idea? Is it possible to do without enabling RDS?
Please let me know if you know something about this, I will be really grateful.

Comment: See this documentation - [Publishing web services](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/developing-applications/using-web-elements-and-external-objects/using-web-services/publishing-web-services.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a webservice for WSDL. Here I'm going to taken an some real time demo url http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl & Coldfusion 2018.  Please follow the below steps.

**Step 1 :** Create webservice in **CFAdmin - > Data & Service - > Webservices**

**Step 2 :** Give the Webservice name & WSDL URL value.  Refer my image here (**TestService.png**) I've created '**TestService**' for the url http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?wsdl.
[image]

**Step 3 :** Once you added it successfully. You can able to see that in "Active Coldfusion WebService Options"

**Step 4 :** With the help of createObject method & webservice value you can call your all methods in your WSDL url. For example,

```
<cfset myObj = createObject('webservice','TestService')>
<cfdump var='#myObj#' abort="true">
```

**Step 5 :** You can see my below dump about demo webservice url Methods & Classes. Refer image dumpService.png
[image]
I hope this will help you to know about simple Webservice.